# How to print null fields as `"myField": null` in JSON from protobuf messages?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Due to complications of legacy API dependencies, I need to print json objects with explicit `"myField": null`, and not omitting it. I have not found a proper way to generate such a result with `JsonFormat`.

The [language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) mentioned `Wrappers use the same representation in JSON as the wrapped primitive type, except that null is allowed and preserved during data conversion and transfer.` I played a bit with the `StringValue` and friends, which seemed to be compiled differently than other regular proto messages (I'm using java). But still I found no way to set `null` as the value, either as the value of the wrapper class, or as the value of the field with the wrapper type in the parent class. Without setting field `myField`, the `JsonFormat.printer().includingDefaultValueFields().print(message);` seems to skip the field completely from the output.

What does `null is allowed and preserved` mean?

I am aware of `google.protobuf.Value`, which indeed can print `"myField": null` correctly, with setting the `NullValue` as the `oneof` field. However, if I get it right, this `Value` essentially erases the type info in proto files -- you can choose to assign almost any data to it. The checks happens in code, not in the definition. This is not something I'd prefer, unless there are no other options.

And I also tried to create my own nullable types, by removing unwanted types from `google.protobuf.Value`, e.g.

```
message NullableString {
  oneof kind {
    google.protobuf.NullValue null_value = 1;
    string value = 2;
  }
}
```

And the output would be like this:

```json
  "stringValue": {
    "nullValue": null
  }
```

So this does not have the blessing of `google.protobuf.Value` which would print `"stringValue": null` directly.

Are there any way to print null values in json that preserves type info in proto?

Answer (score -1):

I too have the same confusion.
I am using proto3 and the Java generated code JsonFormat omit null custom message and null Wellknown Wrapper. This is confusing for human or your client app, but, quote form protobuf doc "if a value is missing or if its value is null, it will be interpreted as the corresponding default value.", this is fine for JSON  deserialization.

Regarding the `null is allowed and preserved`, I agree it's allowed but at least in Java, it's not preserved in serialization.